# Глобальный динамический массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Нужно создать двумерный динамический массив. Размерность массива узнаем в func_1. И этот массив должен быть виден всему файлу, быть глобальным как бы.

```
int func_1
{
   a=GetOb(X);//размерности
   b=GetOb(X);
...создание массива...
   return mas[a][b];
}
void main()
{
   func_1();
}
```

Как вообще можно создать такой массив? Если например создать его в функции `func_1`, и потом в ней же вернуть его через return. можно ли потом уже пользоваться постоянно тем массивом, что вернула функция. или при каждом обращении она  будет заново строить динамический массив?

Comment: Вам скорее всего не хочется глобальный массив. Глобальные данные в сколько-нибудь большом проекте — зло.

Для C++, просто заведите `std::vector< std::vector<T> >` с подходящей областью видимости.

Comment: а если к примеру мне нужно трехмерный вектор,то это нормально? вектор не будет тормозить или память куда нибудь жрать к примеру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаем глобальный указатель. Ну и в функции выделяем память, указатель на которую уже сохраняем в глобальный.

```
int** func_1(int m, int n){
    int **a;
    a = new int*[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        a[i] = new int[n];
    }
    return a;
}

int **array;

int main(){
    int m = 4, n = 3;

    array = func_1(m,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int**` и C++? Ну-ну.

Comment: @VladD, почему?

Comment: Потому что указатель — вещь без семантики. `int**` может быть и указателем на указатель на `int`, и указателем на массив `int`'ов, и массивом указателей на `int` (непонятного размера), и чем угодно.

У `vector<vector<int>>`, в отличие от `int**`, вполне определённая, жёсткая семантика.

Comment: Да, согласен с тем что указатели могут тут и боком вылезти.
Но в задаче конкретно ни на что не указали. Это просто как один из вариантов, возможно не совсем удачных, но простых.

Просто помнится мне, в универе я не раз попадал под раздачу за то что надо было что-то сделать, но применять такие штуки как вектор, да и вообще stl не то чтоб нельзя было - но не рекомендовалось.
А тут задачка как-то так поставлена, как будто её поставили в ВУЗе.

Comment: @Rigiy: Хм. А вы уверены в квалификации преподавателей? В C++, в отличие от C, stl присутствует и является рекомендуемой частью языка. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html

Comment: @VladD Ну на счет их квалификации я не буду судить, в любом случае все самому учить приходится.

Дело в том что они идут строго по программе. И логика такова, что если они про stl не давали лекций, то студент их знать не должен. И лабы надо делать без него, как-то так. А если сделал больше чем давали в лекциях, значит либо не ты делал, либо решил по выделываться, и начинают жутко валить. В общем сплошное расстройство. Рад что это уже в прошлом =)

Comment: у меня это на самообучении все) лучше конечно, чтоб было надежней и быстрее.

Comment: а где оператор ```delete``` , всегда после выделения дин памяти нужно чистить её , мало того что в интернете об етом забывают так еще на  stackoverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253567/%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%81-new-delete-%d0%b2-c