# путаница с new, delete в c++

Tags: c++, память, delete, heap, new

есть вот такой код https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-class-inheritance/ там что-то про наследование .
вот мой вопрос : Почему там нету оператора delete ведь ето постулат что если ты в с++ выделил память(хип она же куча) то и должен её сам почистить , или пользоваться умными указателями.

Вот 2 примера :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "human.h"
#include "teacher.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // Количество учебных часов преподавателя
    unsigned int teacher_work_time = 40;

    teacher *tch = new teacher("Васильков", "Петр", "Сергеевич", teacher_work_time);

    std::cout << tch->get_full_name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Количество часов: " << tch->get_work_time() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
    student *stud = new student("Петров", "Иван", "Алексеевич", scores);

    // Вывод полного имени студента (используется унаследованный метод класса human)
    std::cout << stud->get_full_name() << std::endl;
    // Вывод среднего балла студента
    std::cout << "Средний балл: " << stud->get_average_score() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

почему здесь нету оператора `delete` , ведь дело в том что ето всего лиш один пример ,
есть много кода в интернете с такой же проблемой , или ето не проблема ,просто я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Да просто неаккуратный код, который ориентирован на то, что по завершении программы вся выделенная память все равно будет освобождена...

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Освобождение динамической памяти перед завершением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420070).

Comment: @всмысле будет освобождена , ето же постулат , что если есть ```new```то должен быть обязательно  ```delete``` просто потом будут большие проблемы

Comment: сама память то будет освобождена - ОС обычно очень хорошо знает, сколько памяти взяло приложение. Другое дело, что для объектов не будет вызван деструктор.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю что современные ОС справляться с этим , но ведь как не крути постулат нельзя нарушать , мне об ето все преподаватели  говорили , сначала забыл ```delete``` а потом что ```auto``` использовать вместо ```int``` ,так нельзя писать код . и вот еще , таких примеров в интернете достаточно

Comment: все думают, что они умеют программировать, правда не у всех нормально получается

Answer (score 2):

Преподаватели чуток устарели. Современный модный постулат - в коде не должно быть "сырых" указателей - то есть указателей, не обернутых в умные обертки вроде `unique_ptr` и `shared_ptr`.

Если с `unique_ptr` можно согласиться безоговорочно, он не вносит оверхед и работает весьма предсказуемо, то к `shared_ptr` следует относиться с осторожностью - потому что с ним ресурсы будут течь точно также, как без него, но у разраба будет ощущение благополучия

Comment: но  вы говорите про умные указатели , а я говорю про обычное выделение 
дин. памяти , и всегда нужно за собой чистить память  ето постулат  в независимости от  проекта , выделил хип "ручками", "ручками" его же и очистил

Comment: Так умные указатели на ту и нужны, чтобы память чистилась "сама", особенно 'unique_ptr'

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю , давайте я об'ясню вопрос , почему в большинстве случаев в интернете при выделении дин памяти ручками  то есть без умных указателей , очень часто забывают её почисти , что является грехом .Или я чего-то не понимаю или они ошибаются , а они ошибаются  .

Comment: @andriy-byte - ну, в интернете кто-то не прав. Вы удивлены? Я - нет.

Comment: ну как случилось так и случилось , главное что я был прав и решил вопрос сам для себя

Answer (score 0):

> есть много кода в интернете с такой же проблемой

Потому что 90% кода в интернете - говно. Моё определение "говна" может не совпадать с вашим.

Полная статья тут: https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/05/90.html

Конкретно приведенная вами в пример статья демонстрирует наследование, создание объектов и вызов их методов. Деструкторы (и освобождение памяти) выходят за рамки статьи и никак не описаны. В качестве иллюстрации одного из аспектов этот код допустим. В качестве полноценного проекта - нет.

Comment: насколько я понял ,я прав и всё-таки как минимум преподаватели в университете мен говорили что оператор ```delete ``` нельзя забывать , а как максимум  правила программирования на с++

Comment: думаю, даже в таких маленьких тестовых примерах не стоит забывать о delete. Или создавать объект на стеке и тогда нет никаких проблем с new/delete.